# C parallel server with fork() and pipe()

Tags: c, fork, pipe

I'm trying to create parallel server. It should be able work with more than one client (via telnet) at the same time. I've used fork() to create child processes and pipe() to share variable between parent and child process. My problem is it allows only one connection at the same time, second one must wait till first one have done. I'm new to this so can't find why i get sequential server instead parallel.

```
/* 
 * File:   3LD_parduotuve.c    
 * Author: zuykas
 *
 * Created on April 6, 2013, 4:33 PM
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PORT "1234"
#define BACKLOG 10

void sigchld_handler(int s) {
    while (waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0);
}

void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa) {
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*) sa)->sin_addr);
    }
    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*) sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(void) {
    int sockfd, new_fd;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
    socklen_t sin_size;
    struct sigaction sa;
    int yes = 1;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int rv;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
    return 1;
    }
    for (p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("server: socket");
            continue;
        }
        if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof (int)) == -1) {
            perror("setsockopt");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("server: bind");
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Serveris: failed to bind\n");
        return 2;
    }
    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
    if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }
    sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
            perror("sigaction");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Serveris: laukiama prisijungimo\n");
    //prekiu_sk is variable to be changed in child processes and saved in parent
    int prekiu_sk = 100, tekstas, kl_zinute;
    int kliento_sk;
    char buffer[80];

    int fd1[2];
    pipe(fd1);
    write(fd1[1],&prekiu_sk,sizeof(prekiu_sk));


    while (1) {

    sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
    new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &their_addr, &sin_size);
    if (new_fd == -1) {
        perror("accept");
        continue;
    }
    inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
            get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *) &their_addr), s, sizeof s);
    printf("Serveris: prisijungiama adresu %s\n", s);

    if (!fork()) {
        int skaicius;
        read(fd1[0],&skaicius,sizeof(prekiu_sk));
        close(sockfd);
        if (skaicius<1)
        {
            tekstas = sprintf(buffer, "Sandelyje nebera prekiu.\nRysys nutraukiamas\n");
            send(new_fd, buffer, tekstas, 0);
            write(fd1[1],&skaicius, sizeof(skaicius));
            //close(fd1[0]);
            //close(fd1[1]);
            close(new_fd);
            exit(0);                

        }
        tekstas = sprintf(buffer, "Siuo metu sandalyje uzregistruota %d prekiu.\n", skaicius);
        send(new_fd, buffer, tekstas, 0);
        tekstas = sprintf(buffer, "Iveskite isimamu prekiu skaiciu.\n");
        send(new_fd, buffer, tekstas, 0);
        kl_zinute = recv(new_fd, buffer, sizeof (buffer), 0);
        kliento_sk = atoi(buffer);
        if ((kliento_sk<1) || (kliento_sk>skaicius))
        {
            tekstas = sprintf(buffer, "Neteisingai ivestas isimamu prekiu skaicius.\nRysys nutraukiamas\n");
            send(new_fd, buffer, tekstas, 0);
            write(fd1[1],&skaicius, sizeof(skaicius));
            //close(fd1[0]);
            //close(fd1[1]);
            close(new_fd);
            exit(0); 
        }
        printf("%d \n  %d \n %d", *fd1, kl_zinute, kliento_sk);
        //read(fd1[0],&skaicius,sizeof(prekiu_sk));
        if (skaicius<kliento_sk)
        {
            tekstas = sprintf(buffer, "Likutis sandelyje nepakankamas.\n "
                    "Kazkas pries jus sumazino prekiu kieki.\n"
                    "Rysys nutraukiamas\n");
            send(new_fd, buffer, tekstas, 0);
            write(fd1[1],&skaicius, sizeof(skaicius));
            //close(fd1[0]);
            //close(fd1[1]);
            close(new_fd);
            exit(0); 
        }
        skaicius = skaicius - kliento_sk;
        printf("%d",atoi(buffer));
        tekstas = sprintf(buffer, "Liko %d prekiu \n", skaicius);
        send(new_fd, buffer, tekstas, 0);
        write(fd1[1],&skaicius, sizeof(skaicius));
        printf("%d child %d",*fd1, skaicius);
        //close(fd1[0]);
        //close(fd1[1]);
        close(new_fd);
        exit(0);
    }
    //wait(NULL);
    read(fd1[0],&prekiu_sk,sizeof(prekiu_sk));
    write(fd1[1],&prekiu_sk,sizeof(prekiu_sk));
    //prekiu_sk=prekiu_sk-*fd1;
    printf("\n parent prekiu_sk: %d parent fd: %d \n", prekiu_sk, *fd1);
    close(new_fd);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One fork per socket is fairly expensive. Have you considered handling hundreds of non-blocking sockets on a single thread? You might actually find that concept easier to understand. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are getting serialized by the way you are using the pipe.  Even if I'm wrong about that, seeing both the parent and the child doing both reads and writes on the pipe indicates a problem.  After you call fork, both the parent and the child race for reading from the pipe and that is not likely what you intended.

If you really want to pass information in both directions, create two pipes (one for parent->child traffic, another for child->parent traffic).  After the fork() both processes should immediately close the ends of pipes they are not using, and that will help you keep straight which pipes do what.

If you are writing this as a learning exercise, you might consider several other approaches:

- creating a thread for each connection instead of a process (use MT programming instead of pipes to share data)
- using shared memory to communicate between processes instead of pipes
- using semaphores since your communication needs are minimal
- using a service like inetd to fork your individual servers for you

Just some ideas to get you going...

Comment: Thanks for advice. Finally I found the way to do what I wanted. I've used simple file for passing needed argument instead of pipes.